# Lightdm freezes on startup if wait for GRUB

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, lightdm

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 on [this hardware](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14189359/) (with no external/proprietary driver needed).

[These are the enabled official repositories](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14189374/) (all but proposed)
and [these are the external ones](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14189376/) (Google Chrome, Dropbox, Google Talk Plugin).

[This is my `/etc/default/grub`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14189398/).

The problem is that, if (and only if) I wait for GRUB to finish its countdown, then when I come to Lightdm the system freezes.

I can move the mouse but there is noy input on click, more important there is not keyboard input, (so no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-7</kbd> to investigate and to shutdown, nor SysRq+REISUB, only force shutdown with long press power button).

If at boot I skip the GRUB waiting time (just press Enter), the problem does not appear and everything works great.

Any hint on what might be causing it and how to investigate?

Comment: No hints on this? :( :(

Answer (score 0):

info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration' on ubuntu 15.10 says:

```
'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET'
         In conjunction with 'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT', set this to 'true' ...
         deprecated in favour of the less confusing 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown'.
```